# What is the meaning of an IIS http status code 404.503?

Tags: http-headers, iis-8.5, iis-10

Microsoft lists the IIS http status codes including the substatus codes [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891).

In the 404 section there are substatus codes between 0 and 20, but in my logs I get a 503 as sc-substatus

I can't find any information about it. Don't confuse this with the standard http 503 (Service unavailable) status.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick review of the site in question solved this question. It was setup with `IP Address Restrictions`, the 404.503 is logged for every request that is not from an allowed IP address.

Normally a 403 (Forbidden) status is sent, but in IIS 7+ you can specify which status to return. In the 
'Edit Feature Settings' for IP restrictions choose the 'Deny Action Type':

```
Unauthorized - results in a 401 Unauthorized - IIS-Logs:  401.503
Forbidden    - results in a 403 Forbidden    - IIS-Logs:  403.503
NotFound     - results in a 404 Not Found    - IIS-Logs:  404.503
AbortRequest - results in a Aborted          - IIS-Logs:  not logged
```

Comment: More info can be found at http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions

Comment: which one is recommended? AbortRequest or Forbidden?

Comment: @juFo - I would actually use a 404 NotFound, otherwise you tell a potential attacker that the resource is there but not accessible to him. A 404 is just: "nothing to see here, move along"